# GraphQL rspec tests are all failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

When I run `rails spec:graphql`, all my tests are failing, even though they all pass for my colleagues.

Is there something I could try ? I have the same ruby version and I am updated with the migrations.

Comment: Would you mind sharing more details? Do the tests fail with an error message? What is the error message? What do the tests look like, can you give an example?

Comment: /Users/leonard/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I/Users/leonard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib:/Users/leonard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rspec-support-3.10.2/lib /Users/leonard/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec --pattern ./spec/graphql/\*\*/\*_spec.rb failed